# Regex validation apply to all button on my asp web page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqb3g.png)In my asp web page there are two button i.e. submit and cancel. By submit button I want to submit data(which work perfect.) and on cancel button I want to redirect to home page(which is not work perfect). Before redirect to home page, it fire validation, how to remove that validation and redirect to home page.
thanks in adv.

Comment: Please update your question and add some code.  What type of validation are you using server side validation or client-side validation? Are you calling any validation function on button click?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server"
  Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False">
</asp:Button>
```

[How to Disable Validation for asp.net server controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt244wbb.aspx)